# how to pass id from modal in boostrap to PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, modal-dialog

i am trying to pass an `id` value from `php` to modal . The `id` that i am trying to send comes from a loop. So i am trying to send the value using ajax. The value that i want to send shows up in the console, but it doesn't show on the browser. I checked the network `tab` and i can see the url complete with the desired `id` .  Below is my code that i have tried so far.

```js
$(".manage_permission_button").click(function() {
  var user_id = $(this).attr('user_id');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'assets/pages/manage_users/modal_content_manage_users.php',
    data: {
      user_id: user_id
    },
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      alert(response);
      $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button user_id="<?php echo $value['_id'];?>" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs manage_permission_button">Manage Permission</button>
```

```html
<?php echo $a=$_GET['user_id'];?>
```

[image][image]

EDIT 1:
As you can see in the images the value is not getting fetched in the PHP code , but shows up in the console, and when i physically go to that particular URL

EDIT 2:
This is the modal code

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
     <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Manage Permissions <?php echo $a=$_REQUEST['user_id'];?></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">
           <form action="" method="POST"> 
      <?php include 'permissions.php';?>
       <!-- END TABLE STRIPED -->
       <div class="container-fluid">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn_user_permissions">Submit</button>
       </div>
      </form>
      </div>
     </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I recommend using ```<?= $var ?>``` instead of ```<?php echo $var ?>``` Makes code more readable

Comment: sure .. i'll make sure for next time

Comment: What is your question? Because according to what you wrote everything works correctly. What would you like to achieve?

Comment: i am trying to pass a `PHP` variable to a modal . The variable that i have comes from a loop , so i know i have to use `ajax` so that the values can change dynamically , but the values that i pass does'nt seem to reach the PHP page , i checked the network tab in the console but the values are correctly passed over there . Also if i do `console.log` on the success result the values are visible there also.

Comment: HI harjeev make sure at server page you are using $_GET['user_id'] since request is type is 'GET'

Comment: @Aman . yes aman . i am using $_GET only `<?php echo $a=$_GET['user_id'];?>
`

Comment: @HarjeevSingh It works properly. You echo user id and retrive it in js, and then you log it in console and as you say you get proper id. I just do not see point in sending user_id via ajax to retrive it.

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski . That's because i want to send the php variable to a modal . And i guess we cannot send the value directly as the value would keep on changing depending upon which button the user clicks. Therefore i am using `ajax` so as to pass the value to the modal where the `id` would be displayed.

Comment: Ok, then please provide code with modal

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".manage_permission_button").click(function() {
  var user_id = $(this).attr('user_id');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'assets/pages/manage_users/modal_content_manage_users.php?user_id='+user_id,
    dataType: "html",       
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      alert(response);
      $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
    },
  });
});
```

This Should work try once ! **update** my **answer**

Comment: Yes Aman . i tried passing the values directly on the `url` as well and used `$_GET` on the other side, but it won't fetch . i can't understand the values are showing up in the `console.log` but wont show up in the browser , which is quite confusing.

Comment: try using $_REQUEST instead for just cross checking . also try to verify in url example : domain.com/assets/pages/manage_users/modal_content_manage_users.php?user_id=123

if u see response in Browser

Comment: But this variable is passed properly. And it echoes the id which you display in the console.

Comment: try this ajax now , hope this should work

added :: dataType: "html"

Answer (score 0):

You have `user_id` from `button` on which you click so there is no need to call ajax.

If you want to display user ID in modal do something like this

```
$(".manage_permission_button").click(function() {
    var user_id = $(this).attr('user_id');
    $('#myModal .elementToShowId').html(user_id);
    $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
});
```

So now when you click a button with a class `manage_permission_button` you open modal and insert id using js. There is no need for ajax.

**EDIT**

```
$(".manage_permission_button").click(function() {
    var user_id = $(this).attr('user_id');
    $('#myModal .modal-title').html("Manage Permissions " + user_id);
    $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
});
```

This should work. Try it.

**EDIT2**

If you really want to use ajax you can get modal using ajax.

To do that move your modal code to a separate file, for example `myModal.php` and echo it.

Then in js do something like that

```
$(".manage_permission_button").click(function() {
    var button = $(this),
        user_id = button.attr('user_id');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'assets/pages/manage_users/myModal.php',
        data: {
            user_id: user_id
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $(response).insertAfter(button);
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        },
    });
});

$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

But I do not recommend that method. The use of ajax is unnecessary.

Comment: can you tell me what `elementToShowId` is ?

Comment: Class of an element in which the id should be shown. Can be ```span```, ```div``` or whatever. If you would provide code with modal, I would now where should it be.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Krzysztof Janiszewski is correct. In your case the js code will be:

```
$(".manage_permission_button").click(function() {
  var user_id = $(this).attr('user_id');
  $('#myModal .modal-title').text('Manage Permissions ' + user_id);
  $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
});
```

Btw I think you should edit the form in the modal follow the form from your php file modal_content_manage_users.php. And likely you will need to pass the user_id into a hidden input also.